# Get id of element (in webbrowser) on Mouseover in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cursor, mouse

In vb.net,
In my form, i have a webbrowser and a textbox.
my question is :
Is it possible to get the id of any element in my webbrowser (especialy the id of a cell of a table) and to copy it in my textbox :
-when I click on the element 
or when my mouse is over the element ...
as in firefox when u right click on a element and you click "inspect element" and u get the HTML code(so the ID too) where the mouse is...

I hope i was clear enough, if not, you can ask me more question.

Thanks a lot
best regards

Comment: [`HtmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementfrompoint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: post your code it will be useful to deal with your question

Comment: @wilie the html code (in my webbrowser) is very simple like <table>
<tr>
<td id="number1">56</td>
</tr> </table> and when the cursor is on the cell, i would like my textbox show "number1"

Comment: @visual vincent HtmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint() Seems to be a very interesting solution... Now i need to search how to use it (i m very noob)

Comment: There's an example in the link I gave you.

Comment: @Visual Vincent yes thanks a lot. Itry to modify the code to get the ID in my textbox but no success...

Comment: You've got to subscribe to the event too. Edit your question and show the attempt(s), and make sure to format the code correctly.

Comment: subscribe to the event too ?

Comment: @Visual Vincent I ll work on this. Thanks for your advices

Comment: Yes, you can't just copy paste the code from the article because there's no subscription to the `Click` event. To subscribe to it just add `Handles WebBrowser1.Document.Click` on the end of the first line.

Comment: No problem. You can read a little about [**Handling events on MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9xkz224.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get id of element on `MouseOver`, you must be :

1- Declare a `HtmlDocument`.

2- Assign the `WebBrowser` `Document` to `HtmlDocument`.

3- Create an event handler that retrieves id element on `MouseOver`.

4- Assign the event handler to `HtmlDocument`.

As following :

```
Dim htmlDocument As HtmlDocument

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    htmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
    AddHandler htmlDocument.MouseOver, AddressOf Document_MouseOver
End Sub

Private Sub Document_MouseOver(sender As Object, e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    TextBox1.Text = TryCast(sender, HtmlDocument).GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition).GetAttribute("id")
End Sub
```

Comment: i m looking for this but cant fint it... where can i mark this? the green check?